# Upgrading software in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-installation

I have a program called zlib I need to upgrade. As I've never downloaded it before I suspect it comes with Ubuntu.

Normally I'd just download and compile it, but a different tool (vcftools) is going to use it so I can't just install it locally. I suspect I either need to

1. Install the new version of zlib somewhere and tell the system to look for zlib in the folder I installed it. If zlib is backwards compatible this should be ok, I hope.
2. Upgrade the current version (but sudo apt-get install tells me I have the most recent version)

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `zlib` is a file compression library. Please tell us why you need to update it. Also, what release of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: When I try to run VCFtools I get the following message: "Using zlib version: 1.2.3.3
Versions of zlib >= 1.2.4 will be *much* faster when reading zipped VCF files." And I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-31-generic x86_64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing things a bit. `zlib` is just another locally installed package on your Ubuntu box. I would first see if there is a newer version of `zlib` in one of the Ubuntu/Debian repositories which contain all the software that you can install (prebuilt) for Ubuntu/Debian and other OSes that derive from either of those 2 distros.

```
$ apt-get install zlib
```

But before we do that command let's double check that the package is in fact called `zlib`:

```
$ dpkg -l |grep zlib
ii  zlib1g:amd64                              1:1.2.7.dfsg-13                           amd64        compression library - runtime
```

So it would appear that the package is actually called `zlib1g`. To update it:

```
$ apt-get install zlib1g
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

So I'm stuck at that particular version, or there isn't a newer one available.

#### Another approach

You could fairly easily download the latest version of `zlib`, 1.2.8, and compile it, and then set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, temporarily, to point to your compiled versions of these libraries. This would allow you the ability to try it out, without having to install it on your system just yet.

Once you've set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you can invoke `VCFtools` to try them out.

#### Next steps

Your next option would be to either find a 3rd party repo with a newer version of zlib1g included, or download the source package and build your own .deb file using it. There are numerous tutorials on how to setup your own package building environment and build your first .deb file. It sounds more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: Great advice.  I would emphasize the steps listed under 'Another Approach' to maintain compatibility with existing dependent programs while enabling the features of the newest version of zlib for your application.

Answer (score 2):

A given release of a distribution ships with a given version of each program. That's what a release is all about. (There are “rolling release” distributions, where you spend all your time upgrading to the next version of every piece of software. If you have better things to do with your time, stick with a released distribution.)

The [version of the zlib1g package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zlib1g) in Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) is 1.2.3.4, and the version in Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal) is 1.2.7. You can download the source package (all three files: `.dsc`, `.diff.gz` and `.orig.tar.gz` or `.debian.tar.gz`) from the Ubuntu website, then compile that version as a package.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot
sudo apt-get build-dep zlib
dpkg-source zlib_1.2.7.dfsg-13.dsc
cd zlib-1.2.7.dfsg
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -b -nc
sudo apt-get install ../zlib1g-1.2.7.*.deb
```

Note that installing newer versions of a library could potentially cause incompatibilities. For zlib, I doubt you'll have problems, but this is not something you should do lightly.

Alternatively, install a newer version of the library somewhere in your home directory and use it only for the particular program that needs it. If you compile and install zlib in `~/lib/zlib1.2.8/lib`, here's a suitable wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib/zlib1.2.8/lib
exec vcftools "$@"
```